# Woocommerce call back url after transaction

Tags: woocommerce, ccavenue

I have used woocommerece with ccavenue checkout in my website. but every time after the transaction it  redirect to 
my-website-url/wc-api/WC_Mrova_Ccave with blank page. how can can i set 9it to my chackout page. please help me to get out of this. thanks in advance.

Comment: add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'my_function' ); you can use this hook and redirect it where you want it

Comment: function callback_handler()
{
  wp_redirect(  site_url().'/quick-donation' );  
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'callback_handler' ); 
i have used this code in my function.php but it is not working.

Comment: please help me to solve this problem

Comment: how can i get out of this problem if anyone does no give me answer.

Comment: echo "in function"; and die(); put this in callback_handler to check it is getting called or not

Comment: no it is not getting called. i have put echo in the function but it is not displayed. so it is not getting called.

Comment: have you used die()?

Comment: yes i have used die()